# Facebook custom tab content

Tags: html, facebook, tabs

Does anyone know if it is possible to create HTML pages held on a remote server and displayed inside of a Facebook tab?

If so, can you point out an article about how this is done, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to display that tab on a Fb profile tab or on a Fb page tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey,
you can create your own facebook app. 
Inside you are able to create "facebook-like" tabs and to display anything you want in tabs.

You host the content (code, DB) on your server and thanks to Facebook API, you display it on the app.facebook.com/yourAppName. You can also get tones of informations about users (thanks to permissions on user's profil).

Basically there are to ways to display content : the facebook HTML : FBML (component facebook look/behaviour) and an iFrame (you can combine both to add tabs for instance).

Note : you can't add tabs in the user's profil anymore. 
Note2 : the specifications always change, even the official doc isn't up-to-date. Very difficult to find not deprecated pieces of code.

Comment: Can you provide a link or explanation on how to host external content in an iframe in a Facebook tab? I've tried this in the past and believed it was deprecated.

Comment: First, keep in mind I'm talking about facebook apps : all the displayed content (including FBML) is on my server. The way I do it is : I use FBML (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/) only for facebook-like tabs (because entiere FBML apps are amazingly slow) and below les tabs, I use an iframe to display contents (to avoid "useless" communications between Facebook and my pages).

Comment: Thanks. According to the developer roadmap, support for iframes in page tabs is coming in Q1 2011. How realistic their timescales are I'm unsure http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap

Comment: Thanks. What I meant was o a Business Page, rather than an app.

Answer (score 2):

Complete video tutorial / screencast with transcript is here: [How To Create a Facebook Custom Tab](http://www.foremostresumes.com/resume-writer-blog/2011/03/25/how-to-add-custom-tabs-to-your-facebook-page/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can actually load the content from a file on your own server, but you can however, copy the HTML into Facebook using the [static FBML](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878&b) application.

Comment: You can load IFrame from your server. It is better than static FBML. And it is nicely done as Mathias E. descibed.

Comment: Ivan, can you elaborate? The new tabs system doesn't seem to actually show the tabs anywhere.